# Python won't import module

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the error I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detectron/utils/subprocess.py", line 28, in <module> import numpy as np
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module> from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module> from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module> from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module> import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 74, in <module> from numpy.testing import _numpy_tester
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 10, in <module> from unittest import TestCase
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/__init__.py", line 58, in <module> from .result import TestResult
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/result.py", line 9, in <module> from . import util
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/util.py", line 2, in <module> from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict 

  ImportError: cannot import name namedtuple
```

The issue here is, the module is installed

```
$ ls /usr/lib/python2.7
    ...
    -rwxr--r-- 1 root root  27798 Dec  5  2017 collections.py
    -rwxr--r-- 1 root root  26059 Jul 17 17:40 collections.pyc
    ...
```

If I imported directly from python, it works just fine:

```
$ python
    Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
    [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict
    >>>
```

Here is what $PYTHONPATH has

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
    /usr/lib/python2.7/
```

Here is what $PATH has

```
$ echo $PATH
    /home/deep/bin:/home/deep/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/bin/python
```

Here is what python sees

```
>>> import sys
>>> from pprint import pprint as p
>>> p(sys.path)
['',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/deep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/deep/cocoapi/PythonAPI/Detectron',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycocotools-2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
>>>
```

I was thinking it was some sort of conflict, but I can't tell how...

```
$ sudo find / -name "collections.py"
    /home/deep/cocoapi/PythonAPI/Detectron/detectron/utils/collections.py
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hypothesis/searchstrategy/collections.py
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/future/moves/collections.py
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/collections.py
    /usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py

$ sudo find / -name "collections"
    /usr/lib/python3.5/collections
```

I ran out of ideas; I don't know why I can't import this module. 
Thank you in advance.

***edit:** It seems like

```
/home/deep/cocoapi/PythonAPI/Detectron/detectron/utils/collections.py
```

is causing conflicts. Any way to prioritize the calls, so I can use the python libraries first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sudo find / -name "collections.py"
   /home/deep/cocoapi/PythonAPI/Detectron/detectron/utils/collections.py
```

I think, here might lie the culprit.

There is a module in your detectron package that is named "collections".

I guess, somehow this collections module is imported before the standard collections module is imported.

All modules are stored in memory by their names, after import. So when a different package does again an import of "collections" it will just (because of the name clash) get the wrong module. And because this does not contain namedtuple, you get the error.

Remedy:

- either rename the collections module
- or make sure that it is always imported with package (fully qualified)

Ergo:

- don't use the names of standard modules for your modules -- it is just dangerous.

Comment: Is there a way that maybe I can prioritize the calls? Everything in this project are just libraries, I can't change names... Thank you. I just changed the name of the file you suggested and didn't make a difference.

Comment: I guess, that is one of the reasons, they changed the import system of relative imports in Python 3.x -- to prevent clashes like that.

Comment: Maybe it could help, if you would import the std collections module first in your main program -- before you import the other packages. But than it might happen, that the problematic package is not working, because it can not access its own "collections".

Comment: @Joe: BTW: It did not make a difference? Did you delete the .pyc file?

Comment: (sorry i forgot about the .pyc) You were right, I changed the name of the .pyc too and it fixed the problem. But I would like to keep this file as it is a library.

Comment: if you see the module collections was called from 'unittest don't know why it would prioritize the one in my project...